# periodically send location updates using fusedLocation API

Tags: android, location, alarmmanager, periodic-task, fusedlocationproviderapi

Android programming is a brand new thing to me, i've been playing with android's location and i have a same issue, im going to send a periodic location updates to a server in background and i'm using the AlarmManager/LocationManager approach, set an alarmManager with a defined Interval then when the alarmReceiver is triggered it will get device's current location (using locationManager) and send it to the server on its onReceive method. i found out this FusedLocation as a great replacement as LocationManager give me an additional job to get the best location provider. is it possible to perform sending location updates in background periodically using fusedLocation api without an alarmManager? if so, how can i do that? thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Per the [LocationRequest documentation](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html):

> In between these two extremes is a very common use-case, where applications definitely want to receive updates at a specified interval, and can receive them faster when available, but still want a low power impact. These applications should consider [PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html#PRIORITY_BALANCED_POWER_ACCURACY) combined with a faster [setFastestInterval(long)](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html#setFastestInterval(long)) (such as 1 minute) and a slower [setInterval(long)](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html#setInterval(long)) (such as 60 minutes). They will only be assigned power blame for the interval set by [setInterval(long)](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html#setInterval(long)), but can still receive locations triggered by other applications at a rate up to [setFastestInterval(long)](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html#setFastestInterval(long)). This style of request is appropriate for many location aware applications, including background usage. Do be careful to also throttle [setFastestInterval(long)](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html#setFastestInterval(long)) if you perform heavy-weight work after receiving an update - such as using the network.

This allows you to guarantee you'll get location updates based on the interval you set with [setInterval(long)](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html#setInterval(long)), giving you the equivalent behavior to a periodic alarm, but if other apps request location information, you may get location information as often as your [setFastestInterval(long)](https://developer.android.com/reference/com/google/android/gms/location/LocationRequest.html#setFastestInterval(long)) - you can set your fastest interval to your interval if you just want location updates at a set interval.

Comment: great! thanks, found a useful article here http://www.zionsoft.net/2014/11/google-play-services-locations-2/