# FusedLocation service does not give periodic updates unless location is changed?

Tags: android, google-play-services, fusedlocationproviderapi

I have written service to provide a location updates in my app. The problem is the location service does not give location updates unless the location is changed. I am using emulator to test it. Below is the code:

```
 mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();

     mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
     mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
     mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
     mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
```

based on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29902260/periodically-send-location-updates-using-fusedlocation-api) answer . The setInterval method should return me regular updates.

What is wrong here?

Complete code:

```
package com.followme;

import android.app.IntentService;
import android.app.Service;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.IBinder;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.annotation.Nullable;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.util.Log;

import com.google.android.gms.common.ConnectionResult;
import com.google.android.gms.common.api.GoogleApiClient;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationListener;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationRequest;
import com.google.android.gms.location.LocationServices;

import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.Set;

/**
 * An {@link IntentService} subclass for handling asynchronous task requests in
 * a service on a separate handler thread.
 * <p>
 * TODO: Customize class - update intent actions, extra parameters and static
 * helper methods.
 */
public class LocationService extends Service implements GoogleApiClient.ConnectionCallbacks, LocationListener, GoogleApiClient.OnConnectionFailedListener {


    private static final long UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = 1000;
    private static final long FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS = UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS / 2;
    private static final int MY_PERMISSIONS_REQUEST_LOCATION = 1;
    ;
    private GoogleApiClient mGoogleApiClient;
    private LocationRequest mLocationRequest;



    @Override
    public void onCreate() {
        super.onCreate();
        mGoogleApiClient = new GoogleApiClient.Builder(this)
                .addConnectionCallbacks(this)
                .addOnConnectionFailedListener(this)
                .addApi(LocationServices.API)
                .build();
        mLocationRequest = new LocationRequest();
        mLocationRequest.setInterval(UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
        mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS);
        mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
        Log.i("LOC_SERVICE", "onCreate");
    }

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public IBinder onBind(Intent intent) {
        Log.i("LOC_SERVICE", "onBind");

        return null;
    }

    @Override
    public int onStartCommand(Intent intent, int flags, int startId) {
        Log.i("LOC_SERVICE", "onStartCommand");
        super.onStartCommand(intent,flags,startId);
        mGoogleApiClient.connect();
         return START_STICKY;

    }

    @Override
    public void onConnected(@Nullable Bundle bundle) {
        Log.i("LOC_SERVICE", "onConnected");
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED && ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, android.Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {

            return;
        }
        LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onConnectionSuspended(int i) {

    }


    @Override
    public void onConnectionFailed(@NonNull ConnectionResult connectionResult) {
    Log.e("Location service","conenction failed");
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location) {
        Log.i("LOC_SERVICE", "onLocationChanged");
        final Set<String> senderList = AppUtil.getSendersList(this);
        try {

            final JSONObject msg  = new JSONObject().put("type", "loc").put("lat", location.getLatitude()).put("lng", location.getLongitude()).put("fcm","\""+AppUtil.getFCM(this)+"\"");

           // final String[] fcmArr = senderList.toArray(new String[senderList.size()]);
            AsyncTask.execute(new Runnable() {
                @Override
                public void run() {

                    for(String fcm:senderList) {
                        try {
                            FCMServer.sendMsg(msg, fcm);
                        } catch (IOException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        } catch (JSONException e) {
                            e.printStackTrace();
                        }
                    }
                }
    });
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
}}
```

Comment: Can you provide a little more code?

Comment: Have you tried it on an actual device? I know emulators can be a funky with location mocking...

Comment: @ValentinoS. updated the code

Comment: So I think you are using "LocationServices.FusedLocationApi.requestLocationUpdates(
                mGoogleApiClient, mLocationRequest, this);" to request locations..and you are catching them into a "onLocationChanged(Location location)" callback..

Comment: @ValentinoS. That's rt. The code is working fine since i can catch it when the location gets changed. but not after repeated intervals.

Comment: What's the value of "UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS" and "FASTEST_UPDATE_INTERVAL_IN_MILLISECONDS"?

Comment: Also, what provider are you using? GPS? NETWORK?